# Help Needed With Pascal's Triangle

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I just found an incredible pattern for pascal's triangle (of course this has certainly been observed before but to me this is amazing). So for every third row of pascal's triangle, one of the numbers is double the proceeding. For example,

1

1 1

1 2 1 ***

1 3 3 1

1 4 6 4 1

1 5 10 10 5 1 ***

So for the third row and the sixth row, one of the numbers is double the previous. How do I prove that this is true for all rows (so every third row has this pattern?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
$$ \frac{(3k-1)!}{(k-1)! \; (2k)!} = \frac{1}{2k} \; \frac{(3k-1)!}{(k-1)! \; (2k-1)!}  $$

$$ \frac{(3k-1)!}{k! \; (2k-1)!} = \frac{1}{k} \; \frac{(3k-1)!}{(k-1)! \; (2k-1)!}  $$
so the second is twice the first. Row 14 is the only occurrence of three consecutive entries in proportion $(1,2,3),$  those being $1001, 2002, 3003$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
3k-1 \\
k-1 \\
\end{array}
\right) = 
\frac{1}{2k}
\; \frac{(3k-1)!}{(k-1)! \; (2k-1)!} 
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
3k-1 \\
k \\
\end{array}
\right) = 
\frac{1}{k}
\; \frac{(3k-1)!}{(k-1)! \; (2k-1)!} 
$$

$$
2
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
3k-1 \\
k-1 \\
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
3k-1 \\
k  \\
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

IF
$$
3
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
3k-1 \\
k-1 \\
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
3k-1 \\
k+1  \\
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
then
$$  \frac{3}{2k(2k-1)} = \frac{1}{k(k+1)} $$
and $$ 3 k^2 + 3k = 4 k^2 - 2k $$  and
$$  0 = k^2 - 5k = k(k-5)$$
With $k=5$ we get $3k-1=14$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On row $n$ the number at position $k$ is ${n\choose k}$. So saying that the number at position $k+1$ is double the number at the preceding position $k$ is the same as the equation
$$
{n\choose k+1}=2{n\choose k}\tag1
$$
which by definition of binomial coefficient is the same as
$$
\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}=2\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.\tag2
$$
Using the identities $(k+1)!=(k+1)k!$ and $(n-k)!=(n-k)(n-k-1)!$, equation (2) simplifies to the following relation between $n$ and $k$:
$$n=3k+2.\tag3$$
In other words, this phenomenon occurs for rows $n=2, 5, 8,\ldots$, that is, every third row starting at $n=2$. Rearranging (3) into the form $k=(n-2)/3$ gives the positions $k$ and $k+1$ where the doubling occurs.

You can use this approach to discover the places in Pascal's triangle where the number at position $k$ is the same as the number at position $k+1$ -- this occurs every other row.